# Can't see CMD.EXE on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I have a problem with Windows 7 and `cmd.exe` with these conditions:

- Logon as non admin user
- Launch `cmd.exe`

I can see `cmd.exe` in task manager but it's invisible in the desktop and I don't know what to do, everything is fine and I can see `cmd.exe` if I do login with an admin account. I can see it in the "Process" tab but not in the "Application" tab, and if I launch five `cmd.exe`'s, I see five processes, but from that tab I have no "Bring to front" or "Maximise"

I can't find any WOW folder under `C:\Windows`, even with show hidden and system files enabled.

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit running on a 64-bit Intel Core 2 Duo E7500

Comment: Is it a 64 bit machine running windows 7 32 bits, by any chance?

Comment: Does right clicking on cmd.exe in task manager and selecting bring to front or maximise do anything?

Answer (score 2):

The Window has been set to invalid screen coordinates, but it is easy to fix:

1. Click the command-prompt button the taskbar
2. Press the following keys:

   1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
   2. <kbd>S</kbd>
   3. Any of the arrow keys (e.g., <kbd>→</kbd>)
3. Move the mouse (the command-prompt window should now be on screen)
4. Save the new position by pressing the following keys:

   1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
   2. <kbd>P</kbd>
   3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>

Now close the command-prompt and open another one. The window should be on screen.

(Note, the method above for saving the position exploits [a bug](https://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7) in Windows 7. You can select *Defaults* in the context-menu instead of *Properties* if Microsoft ever decides to fix the bug. Also, for Windows XP, you can do the same actions, but must select *Modify shortcut that started this window* after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try to search it inside the WOW folder under Windows folder. When u run win7 32bits inside a 64bits machine, the windows creates a folder called WOW (Windows on Windows) where it stores some of the 32 bits applications. Try it and

Comment: The WOW folder is only there if you run 64 bit Windows, if you run a regular copy of Windows 32 there will be no such folder even if the processor is 64 bit.