# How can I widen the Windows 7 Command Prompt window?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

How can I widen the Windows 7 command prompt window?

It's fixed at 80 columns in width and dragging the window edges won't let me make it any bigger than that.

Comment: Thanks for asking... apparently this is a common problem.  Any idea why MS decided to make this obscure behavior the default?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes. To change the screen buffer or window size:

- **Click** the icon at the left of the title bar.
- **Click** `Properties` (or `Defaults` for persistent properties) <sup>Thanks [@Scott](https://superuser.com/questions/401621/widen-the-win-7-command-prompt-window/401623#comment456484_401623)</sup>

  [image: Properties]
- Go to the `Layout` tab
- Change the settings accordingly

  [image: Layout]
- **Click** `OK` to save.

Comment: You can also click Defaults instead of Properties to make the changes stay when you close and re-open the command prompt. (you beat me to the answer, I was going to include pictures :) )

Comment: A good solution to a problem that shouldn't even exist.  Thanks to all.

Comment: *> You can also click Defaults instead of Properties to make the changes stay when you close and re-open the command prompt.*   Actually, in Windows 7, the *Properties* and *Default* options [are the same](http://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7). `:-(`

Answer (score 13):

You might want to try typing:

```
mode 120,100
```

Should widen it significantly.

Comment: Awesome!  I hope the setting is persistent, but this does what I wanted.

Comment: Btw, I entered "help mode" on the command line to learn about the 'mode' command.  The Help is rather cryptic but apparently the first number is the number of columns and the second is the number of lines.

Answer (score 10):

Type this on command line:

```
mode con:cols=140 lines=70
```

Where `140` is the width in columns and `70` is the height in lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) on top of cmd.exe, which have (except other things) resizeable window