# Increase width of command line / cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Widen the Win 7 command prompt window?](https://superuser.com/questions/401621/widen-the-win-7-command-prompt-window)

Any way to change the width of the windows command line / cmd.exe? How about using another "shell", is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the title bar --> Properties --> Layout Tab
You can set the layout of the window there.

Another option is to use the `mode` command.

```
mode <cols>,<lines>
mode 80,25
mode 120,50
```

You could also use a different terminal application, such as [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/),

Comment: cool, didn't know that! Thank you! I'll stick with cmd.exe as long as possible :-)