# win7's cmd.exe doesn't show up

Tags: windows-7, command-line, console, window

When I run cmd.exe, its window doesn't show up.

Still, cmd.exe is listed in the processes list of the task manager.

And unfortunately, it doesn't figure in the taskbar.

Is the problem related to the file itself or the registry?

Repairing windows using the dvd did nothing

System: Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bits

Comment: Does it have a taskbar button?

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Do I have to replace cmd.exe or edit the registry?

Comment: What about http://superuser.com/questions/87441/alternative-windows-command-shell-and-console ?

Comment: @Shiki I tried PowerSell, [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and ColorConsole. All of them are alternatives but they don't solve completely the problem.

Comment: Did you mean, that ConEmu (btw, did you try it?) or Console works with all console programs, but running standalone - console window does not appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete key

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
```

Save its contents in reg-file before deletion!

Comment: That's strange; the console registry entry has no settings that should effect it having a taskbar button or not. `o.O`

Comment: Nothing strange. Just another bug from M$. I have already encountered this problem, while developing [ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/). As far as I remember, the problem is in one incorrect value, not sure now what exactly.

Comment: `"FullScreen"=dword:00000001` and oops. This "works" on 32-bit Win7.

Answer (score 5):

The Window has been set to invalid screen coordinates, but it is easy to fix:

1. Click the command-prompt button the taskbar
2. Press the following keys:

   1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
   2. <kbd>S</kbd>
   3. Any of the arrow keys (e.g., <kbd>→</kbd>)
3. Move the mouse (the command-prompt window should now be on screen)
4. Save the new position by pressing the following keys:

   1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
   2. <kbd>P</kbd>
   3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>

Now close the command-prompt and open another one. The window should be on screen.

(Note, the method above for saving the position exploits [a bug](https://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7) in Windows 7. You can select *Defaults* in the context-menu instead of *Properties* if Microsoft ever decides to fix the bug. Also, for Windows XP, you can do the same actions, but must select *Modify shortcut that started this window* after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.)

Comment: This doesn't work, it doesn't have a taskbar button

Comment: The window doesn't show up even for other .exe programs that uses the command prompt, like compiled c programs

Answer (score 1):

You can select your window on taskbar and press Winkey+arrow keys. This works with many displays as well (when you disconnect second display and program opens on it).