# What's the difference between Defaults and Properties when changing cmd.exe or PowerShell's settings?

Tags: command-line, windows-8, powershell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Temporarily Changing Console Properties in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7)

I want to change the font used by both **cmd.exe** and PowerShell.  When I right click in the window border, I see both Defaults and Properties:

[image: CMD.exe screenshot]

What's the difference?  One would think Defaults was for all sessions, and Properties was for the current session.  However, changes to Properties are persisted even after relaunching **cmd.exe**.

Another problem is that changing the font in either Defaults or Properties doesn't actually change the font.  This is on Windows 8.

Comment: Seems they didn't fix it after breaking it in Windows 7 (Vista?): [Temporarily Changing Console Properties in Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/323059/temporarily-changing-console-properties-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 7):

I googled for `"command prompt" menu site:microsoft.com`, the first result pointed to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff758104.aspx. Here is an excerpt:

> - **Properties.** Changes you make here affect the current session. When you leave the properties dialog box, <strike>you'll be given the option of propagating</strike> your changes [will propagate] to the shortcut from which this session was launched. If you accept, all future sessions launched from that shortcut will also use the new settings.
> - **Defaults.** Changes will not affect the current session but instead will affect all future sessions (except for those launched from a shortcut whose properties have been customized). These changes also affect future sessions in character-mode, MS-DOS-based applications that do not have a program-information file (PIF) and do not store their own settings.
>
> Note that when you use the second method, choosing **Defaults,** you also get the option to enable and disable the AutoComplete option, which is enabled by default.

In my experience, Windows 7 Command Prompt saves changes made to the current session (e.g. background colour) without asking the user.

Answer (score 2):

**Experiment:**

Cmd Prompt: Taskbar Shortcut:
Black (background): White: (text)
Set Default: Green: Magenta (Yuk)

Create a Metro Shortcut for Cmd Prompt
It obeys the default: Green: Magenta:
Return to Taskbar cmd shortcut
Black: White [Incidentally, Default still shows Green: Magenta]

**Conclusion:**

Properties is for that cmd shortcut:
Default sets the colours for any shortcuts you create down the line.
Default only affects new shortcuts, existing ones keep their ‘Properties’.

Tip: Look compare the Default and Properties for each shortcut.