# Windows theme resets everytime computer is restarted after registry modification?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, windows-registry, themes

I had gotten bored one day and changed the colors/fonts of the command prompt, then finally i wanted to, undo this and change the color/font scheme of the windows command prompt `cmd.exe` back to the real default one with the black background, and plain white text. Like the color it would be if you just installed windows.

After some research, i found this answer on here: [How to reset the looks of the Command Prompt window, in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/609470/how-to-reset-the-looks-of-the-command-prompt-window-in-windows)

I tried to follow what the answer says, i opened up `regedit` and deleted the `Console` folder under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. I did an export prior to deletion as suggested.

Now my command prompt is back to the default appearance, which is what i wanted, but now whenever i restart my computer, my windows theme gets changed from the classic looking one, to the windows 7 look theme.

The theme i had prior and want is the one you get by going `Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Performance > Settings > Adjust for best performance.`

That radio button is still selected, but doesn't look how it should.

I use to be able to retain the classic "performance oriented" across restarts just fine, before i messed around with the above registry files in an attempt to get the default colored console back.

I also have a different computer (same OS), that can keep the theme just fine after restarts.

Is this a windows bug or did i break something?

Im on windows 7 home premium 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme issue is a problem with Windows 7 and not related to your particular modifications.  Not that it's any help, but the problem appears to be fixed in Windows 8.1 (I didn't use 8 so I can't speak to it).

The best I have been able find to deal with the problem is to save your theme with some name like MyTheme and then open up Personalize and reselect it after rebooting.  It's not the answer I was looking for either, but I doubt MS will fix it since they haven't done so already (unless a big customer puts some weight into it).

Comment: The problem though is that before the registry modification i made, i could restart the computer and the classic "best performance" theme i selected would be the one the computer defaults to (which is what i want), but after i made this registry modification, the theme changes itself after restart. Also a different computer i own (Windows 7 home premium 64 bit) can be restarted and keep the classic "best performance" theme just fine?

Comment: Well, it wasn't always this way for me either. I believe Microsoft blames "3rd party software" but it seems more often likely a corruption of the user profile. In my experience, Vista was much worse after an equivalent amount of use and things got better with 7 and it's probably too soon to say 8 is great. If you don't mind starting your customizations over you can create a new user and see if it doesn't work again with the new user account. (I would rather reset the theme profile every time I reboot since with 7 I mostly only have to reboot for windows update.)

Comment: After some more troubleshooting, i found that changing the theme in the admin account on the computer to the classic "performance oriented" one i want to use in my normal account, now lets the normal account keep this classic "performance oriented" theme selected after restarting. So maybe the registry modification i made, aggravated the bug you are talking about in some way. But ya like you say, something is funky with the theme functionality.

Comment: That's interesting that one account had an effect on the other..