# How to enable the new console in Windows 10 and what are its defaults?

Tags: command-line, windows-10

I expected to get to see the new console earlier in the preview, but I just was greeted by a completely different looking command prompt (not PowerShell) after installing Windows 10 *without* providing a Microsoft account or syncing settings.

How do I enable it and what are the default settings? Tips from [How to reset the looks of the Command Prompt window, in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/609470/252532) didn't seem to work.

**Top:** legacy style with raster fonts and (80x25) – **Bottom:** new default with *Consolas* (120x30)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unticking the *Use legacy console* option in the menu or adding the following registry key should enable the new console:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"ForceV2"=dword:00000001
```

Some more values with explanation:

> `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]` – all DWORD values
>
> - **`Registry Key` – Description**
> - `ForceV2` – `1` for new console features, `0` to disable new console.
> - `LineSelection` – `1` to enable line selection, `0` for block mode only.
> - `FilterOnPaste` – `1` to enable new paste behavior.
> - `LineWrap` – `1` to wrap text on resize operations.
> - `CtrlKeyShortcutsDisabled` – `0` to enable new key shortcuts, `1` to disable.
> - `ExtendedEditKeys` – `1` to enable a full set of keyboard selection keys, `0` to disable.
> - `TrimLeadingZeros` – `1` to trim leading zeroes on double-click selection, 0 to keep them.
> - `WindowsAlpha` – Adjust opacity between 30% and 100%: 0x4C to 0xFF -or- 76 to 255.
> - `WordDelimiters` – By default, only the space character is used when selecting text word-by-word with
>     <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ARROW</kbd> keys. Set this
>     REG_SZ value to contain all the characters you wish to treat as
>     delimiters.

<sup>Source: [Console Improvements in the Windows 10 Technical Preview](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/)</sup>

I haven't found a way to reset settings or export the default settings, so here is a screenshot showing all the options out of the box without synchronized settings:

[image]

**Edit:** I thought I had too look for particular registry settings, but it looks like the different .lnk files contain the settings.