# CMD Prompt is blank, no text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, blank-screen

When i open `.cmd`, `.bat` files or `cmd`, it shows as A blank window, with no text.

My questions :

> - What causes this problem?
> - How can I fix it?

Some screenshots to give more info about my problem :

When I try to open CMD :[image]

When I try to open a batch file :[image]

Comment: Try to copy your cmd.exe into some folder not listed in %PATH% - does it is started with the same issue? Check if cmd.exe is altered/damaged. Does some command-line utility (ping, for example) is started without any problems? Check session and global environ variables, cmd.exe properties, shortcuts, etc... Try to set "use ps in cmd window" and then revert back.

Comment: Is this a geneal fonts problem in windows or only in command prompt?

Comment: @Akina : All apps start correctly. cmd.exe is not damaged. Global environ variables are normal.

Comment: @RicardoBohner: Only cmd.

Comment: *Try to copy your cmd.exe into some folder not listed in %PATH% - does it is started with the same issue?* Create a shortcut to such file specifying full pathname for it and the starting folder equal to its folder. Does this shortcut is started normally?

Comment: @Akina : Creating a shortcut to `cmd.exe` doesn't work. Copying cmd to a folder not listed in %path% also doesn't work.

Comment: I would run *regedit* and look at all the folders and keys that have the 'cmd.exe' substring for the presence of obviously unnecessary additions to the execution line. Searching by the folder/parameter name would help to understand does the parameter value is correct.

Comment: @Akina: Nvm, found a solution. Check my solution below

Comment: I have seen. But this is more troubleshooting regime than normal one, some new settings will be disabled, some additional abilities will be unavailable... I'd prefer to heal the reason, not symptoms.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just need a functional cmd that can run commands, I don't need fancy settings.

Comment: Try changing the color of the text of the command prompt to yellow with black background with the following command: color 0e

Comment: @RicardoBohner: I can't type anything in the CMD prompt.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you can type but you only don't see what you type. Have tyou tried opening the command prompt with another user on you computer? If you don't have anther user you could create one>
You could also use cmd.exe from powershell, in a powershell you could type cmd.exe and use powershell as if it was cmd.exe.

You could also try the solution proposed here: https://superuser.com/questions/609470/how-to-reset-the-looks-of-the-command-prompt-window-in-windows

Comment: Yes, I use cmd in powershell now. Haven't tried changing the color. Using cmd on another user doesn't fix it.

Comment: Changing the color works, see my answer below.

Comment: This problem occurred after I shortly enabled command prompt legacy mode. After switching back, all the text was gone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step by step solution that I used :

> 1. Open `regedit.exe`
> 2. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`.
> 3. If the `Autorun` string value exists, delete it.
> 4. Right Click > New > String value.
> 5. Name it `Autorun`.
> 6. Right Click > Modify
> 7. Replace the `Value data` with `color 0f & color 0f`.
> 8. Press OK.

*You can replace `color 0f` with `color (any color)`.*

*Some helpful articles :*

- http://www.herongyang.com/Windows-Security/PWS-Command-Processor-AutoRun-Registry-Value.html
- https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.

Comment: @RicardoBohner: No problem

Answer (score 0):

The Answer above me is good, but it is a bit complicated and for some, very few but still, it is risking messing with things they should not, so here is a simpler solution, just in case:
Rightclick the toolbar > Properties > Terminal:

[image: Right click there or really anywhere within the area]

[image: You should have properties there, my system is in german if you haven't already noticed it]

[image: Here you can then set your preferred Back- and Foreground colors]

Here you may set any color combination you prefer.

Comment: Note: "Properties" (Eigenschaften) changes the settings for the currently running `cmd` instance only. To change the settings for future instances, use "Defaults" (Standardwerte) instead. (Feel free to extend your answer accordingly)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just noticed it right now 